# Access Raphael path programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am drawing raphael path and assigning an id to them using " eye.node.id". I am trying to get the id problematically to change the color using:

```
             `var selectedBodyPart = p.getById(1001);
             selectedBodyPart.attr('fill', 'blue');`
```

But it does not work. my fiddle is :
http://jsfiddle.net/RaoBurugula/okgdtzzh/3/
note : i have added the jquery reference but still consol gives me an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

HTML

```
       <div id="bodyMapContainer">
       </div>
```

JS

```
        //RAPAEL PAGE
       width = 700;
      height = 900;
      var bodyMapContainer = document.getElementById("bodyMapContainer");
      var p = Raphael(20,0,width,height);
      //var p = Raphael(bodyMapContainer,"100%","100%");
      p.rect(0,0,width,height);
      p.setViewBox(0,0,width,height,true); 
      drawEyes(150,45, 11, "Left Eye");
      drawEyes(129,46, 11, "Right Eye");

      //ID for the eyes
      var eyeId = 1000;
      selectEye();

      function drawEyes(xCoordinate,yCoordinate, radius, bodyPartName){
          var eye = p.circle(xCoordinate,yCoordinate, radius);   
          eyeId ++;
          eye.node.id= eyeId;
          eye.title=bodyPartName;
          eye.attr ("stroke", "#F3F3FE");
          eye.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
          eye.click(bodyPartClicked);
          eye.attr('fill', 'red');
      }

      // Hover in function
      function hoverIn() {

          this.attr('fill', 'green');
          console.log($(this).attr('id'));
      }

      // Hover out function
      function hoverOut() {

          this.attr('fill', 'red');
      }

      function bodyPartClicked(){
          var selectedBodyPart =   $(this).attr('title');
          console.log($(this).attr('title'));
          console.log($(this).attr('id'));
      }

      function selectEye(){
          var selectedBodyPart = p.getById(1001);
          selectedBodyPart.attr('fill', 'blue');
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems here, one with the fiddle, and two with the code.

The fiddle problem, just doesn't have a loadable jquery, so I have added that into the jsfiddle itself on the lhs.

For the code, the problem is that you are defining

```
 var eyeId = 1000;
```

after you call drawEyes(), which uses them.

Also for the id, use

```
    eye.id= eyeId;
```

rather than using node

Swap them around, and it should work.

eg [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianscoding/okgdtzzh/5/)